# how to load another local js from a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When press a button, the browser should reload the page and show a different reactjs component/file.

I tried doing things like `href="./code.js"` or `window.location="./code.js"` inside the props button. However, it didn't work. Now, I'm trying with a function, but it's still not working. I'm not really sure how it works.

```
handleClick = () => href="./mycode.js"

export default () => (
  ...
    <Button secondary onClick={this.handleClick}>Registrarse</Button>
  ...);
```

The error is:

```
./src/Menu.js
  Line 4:   'handleClick' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 4:  'href' is not defined         no-undef
```

I don't think my implementation is working correctly.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are you using [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)? Can you edit your question to add your entire react component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use react router to handle routes and moving between your pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add another script file, then inside the `handleClick` create new script tag, set `src` property and append it to the `DOM`.

```
handleClick = () => {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'code.js';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```